# Respuesta incompleta

Tags: java

Buen día quisiera ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio el error que los datos capturados me los muestra incompletos, ya sea antes o después del espacio

La respuesta que me da aparece incompleta

"Ciudades del mundo"

Digite el nombre de la Ciudad:

Jayaque

Digite el nombre del País:

La Libertad

Jayaque es una ciudad que queda en Libertad

```
package ejercicio4;
public class Ciudades 
{
private String nomCiudad;
private String pais;

void setNomCiudad (String C)
 {    nomCiudad=C; }  

String getNomCiudad()
{    return nomCiudad;}  

void setPais (String P)
 {    pais=P; }  

String getPais()
{    return pais;}  

public void mensaje(String m1,String m2)
        {
        System.out.println(m1+" es una ciudad que queda en "+m2);
        }
Ciudades () 
{
    System.out.println ( "\"Ciudades del mundo\"" );
}
       
}
```

```
package ejercicio4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio4 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Ciudades c1=new Ciudades();
    Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Digite el nombre de la Ciudad:\n");
    c1.setNomCiudad(leer.next());
    System.out.println("Digite el nombre del País:");
    c1.setPais(leer.next()); 
    c1.setPais(leer.next()); 
    c1.mensaje(c1.getNomCiudad(),c1.getPais());
    }  
}
```

Comment: el ajuste está en el next del leer. Debes reemplazar el next por el nextline

Comment: Muchas gracias eso era Bendiciones

Comment: vale, me alegro que te halla servido. Publiqué la respuesta para hacerme entender mejor, pero bueno. Ya lograste dar con la solución. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

como mencionaba en el comentario, debes capturar la linea completa, con el next solo vas a obtener cada bloque de texto.

Ajusta el código reemplazando `next()` por `nextLine()`, quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ciudades c1=new Ciudades();
        Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Digite el nombre de la Ciudad:\n");
        c1.setNomCiudad(leer.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite el nombre del País:");
        c1.setPais(leer.nextLine()); 

        c1.mensaje(c1.getNomCiudad(),c1.getPais());

        leer.close();
    }

}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.